# Filtering by case-sensitive string equality

Tags: google-sheets

I discovered (when answering [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/63021)) that string comparison in `filter` is case insensitive: the formulas `=filter(A:A, B:B = "Yes")` and `=filter(A:A, B:B = "YES")` have the same output.

Apparently, this is true generally for string comparison in Google Sheets: `="Y"="y"` returns TRUE, and so does its equivalent `=eq("Y", "y")`.

This is convenient sometimes, but what to do when I want to filter rows by case-sensitive string equality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Short answer

Use `REGEXMATCH(text, regular_expression)` instead of `=` or `EQ(value1,value2)` to set the conditions for `FILTER(range,condition1,[condition2, ...])`

## Demostration

### Data source

```
+---+---------+---------+
|   |    A    |    B    |
+---+---------+---------+
| 1 | Field 1 | Field 2 |
| 2 | Yes     | A       |
| 3 | YES     | B       |
| 4 | no      | C       |
| 5 | No      | D       |
| 6 | NO      | E       |
| 7 | yes     | F       |
+---+---------+---------+
```

### Formula in D1

```
=FILTER(A2:B7,REGEXMATCH(A2:A7,"^yes$"))
```

(The word is placed between ^ and $, so that the entire cell content is required to match it.)

### Result

```
+---+-----+---+
|   |  D  | E |
+---+-----+---+
| 1 | yes | F |
+---+-----+---+
```

Comment: @404: Thanks. I updated the formula.

Answer (score 4):

## Short answer

Instead of FILTER use QUERY

## Demostration

### Data source

```
+---+---------+---------+
|   |    A    |    B    |
+---+---------+---------+
| 1 | Field 1 | Field 2 |
| 2 | Yes     | A       |
| 3 | YES     | B       |
| 4 | no      | C       |
| 5 | No      | D       |
| 6 | NO      | E       |
| 7 | yes     | F       |
+---+---------+---------+
```

### Formula in D1

```
=QUERY(A1:B7,"select B where A = 'yes'",1)
```

### Result

```
+---+---------+
|   |    D    |
+---+---------+
| 1 | Field 2 |
| 2 | F       |
+---+---------+
```

Comment: Makes sense, but is not a completely satisfying answer. There are things that filter does and query cannot do, like handle columns with both strings and numbers.

Comment: @404: The question doesn't mention that handling strings and numbers features are relevant, by the other side, numbers are not case sensitive ;).